# How would you setup default dockerfile per project with an Azure pipeline to handle them?

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

As of now I have a simple solution structure(WebAPI projects, which are gonna be microservices) with default generated dockerfiles for each project in the solution, like:

```
Solution X
|    Project A
|    |    Dockerfile
|    Project B
|    |    Dockerfile
|    Project C
|    |    Dockerfile
|    Project D
|    |    Dockerfile
|    azure-pipeline.yml
```

From the development and debuggind point of view everything works(through "Docker" as launcher), but after creating with the Azure wizard the first pipeline for the "Project A" my build always fails at a COPY instruction at the build step:

```
COPY ["Project A/ProjectA.csproj", "Project A/"]
```

With the error from the pipeline run as:

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder196561826/Project A/ProjectA.csproj: no such file or directory
##[error]COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder196561826/Project A/ProjectA.csproj: no such file or directory
```

Am not an expert in docker neither in azure but I guess I'm setting up this solution in the wrong way to accomplish such thing.

What could be a better setup or fix?

Comment: What is your build context set to?  My guess is that's set to be the project folder which would make the path you're using for the `COPY` command to be incorrect since it should be relative to that folder. Otherwise, you need to set the build context to the solution folder.

Comment: @MattThalman Where I can find this info? How would you setup the context? Also in the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: It's set when running the `docker build` command.  Can you provide how you're executing that?

Comment: @MattThalman I just press the button play for Docker in Visual Studio, and from the command line of VS I the `Dockerfile` commands running an the steps in the file

Comment: But you said it was the Azure pipeline that was failing, not VS.  How is the Azure pipeline executing the Docker build?

Comment: May I know what’s the status of this? Does below method is help to solving issue?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT solved, the mismatch is real between the local development with docker and the one that needs to be setup on Azure devOps to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no such file or directory

This is a very common error people encountered after they migrate the Docker project from `Visual studio` into `Azure Devops`, even they can build docker very successfully in local.

This caused by the different work logic between `Visual Studio(local)` and `Azure Devops`. For local, the docker runs at the `Repos/solution level`. **BUT**, for Azure devops CI, it running the docker in the directory where the dockerfile lives, which is at `project level`. At this time, the relevant path which work fine locally, will not suitable in Azure devops any more.

---

I guess you may not want to make changes to your dockerfile. So here you just need specify the `build context` in Docker task:

Specify `$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)` to the `Docker 2.*` argument `Build context`.

[image]

*Check my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966285/dotnet-publish-on-linux-error-in-docker-azure-devops-build/60973776#60973776).*

Comment: Sorry for the late recognition, in the end I did also figure out this difference, but it was quite a headache, this kind of info should be in a big red notification status on the appropriate documentation pages.